Same integral giving different results
I am trying to solve the following integral using Mathematica
$\int_{0}^1 dz \int_{0}^{1} dz' \exp(-k|z-z'|)\cos[\pi p z] \cos[\pi q z]$,
with $p,q\in \mathbb{Z}$. To do so, I am doing the following:
result1 =Integrate[Integrate[E^(-k*Abs[zp-z])Cos[π p z]Cos[π q zp],{z,0,1}],{zp,0,1}];
FullSimplify[result1, Assumptions -> {{p, q} ∈ Integers}]

which gives

If we now take $p=q$ via
FullSimplify[(E^-k((-1)^p+(-1)^q-(1+(-1)^(p + q)) E^k) k^2)/((k^2+p^2 π^2)(k^2 + π^2 q^2)) /. {p -> q}]

I obtain

The intriguing part happens if, instead of choosing the path above, I compute direct the integral for $p=q$ via
$\int_{0}^1 dz \int_{0}^{1} dz' \exp(-k|z-z'|)\cos[\pi p z] \cos[\pi p z]$,
result2=Integrate[Integrate[E^(-k Abs[zp-z]) Cos[π p z] Cos[π p zp],{z,0,1}],{zp,0,1}];
FullSimplify[result2, Assumptions -> {p} ∈ Integers]

yielding a completely different result.

Do you have any idea why I am getting this?

This is not surprising.
result1 = (E^-k (k Cos[Pi q] (k Pi (p^2-q^2)+E^k p (2 k^2+Pi^2 (p^2+q^2)) Sin[p Pi])
-k Cos[p Pi] (k Pi (-p^2+q^2)+E^k k Pi (p^2-q^2) Cos[Pi q]+E^k q (2 k^2+Pi^2 (p^2+q^2)) 
Sin[Pi q])+Pi (p^2-q^2) (-k (E^k k+Pi q Sin[Pi q])+p Pi Sin[p Pi] 
(-k+E^k Pi q Sin[Pi q]))))/(Pi (k^2+p^2 Pi^2) (p^2-q^2) (k^2+Pi^2 q^2))

is not well defined at $p=q$. So you need to take the limit $p$ → $q$. But this conflicts with the assumption that $p$ and $q$ are integers. To illustrate where is the problem, I take up much simpler example. Consider the case
test = (Sin[p Pi] - Sin[q Pi])/(p - q)

Then
FullSimplify[test, Assumptions -> {q \[Element] Integers, p \[Element] Integers}]

gives 0 as expected. But if you take the limit, MMA answers correctly
Limit[test, p -> q]

(* Pi Cos[Pi q] *)

which is non-zero for any integer $q$.

One way to confirm there is no difference in the two results when q=p is like this:
Simplify[Limit[result1-result2,q->p],Element[p,Integers]]

(* 0 *)

